# How to publish facebook photo with multipart/form-data

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, publish, multipartform-data

With an Android app, i'm trying to publish a photo to facebook wall, using graph-api reference:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("source", "{image-data}");
/* make the API call */
new Request(
    session,
    "/me/photos",
    params,
    HttpMethod.POST,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

I can easily upload picture passing image url to "source" but i want to send multipart/form-data from my FileInputStream WITHOUT uploading to a server.

Someone can explain me how to generate a string from "The photo, encoded as form data"?
I've tryed this method but it seems doesn't to work:

```
static final String GetMultipartFormData(InputStream fileInputStream)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";

    try
    {                       
        sb.append(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        sb.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"fileName.jpg\"" + lineEnd);
        sb.append(lineEnd);

        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }                           

        sb.append(lineEnd);
        sb.append(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        fileInputStream.close();            

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works encoding the image in this way:

```
Bitmap photo; //This is the bitmap of your photo
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

and passing the image to the Bundle:

```
params.putByteArray("source",byteArray);
```